# How to force refresh all devices connected to the website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a website and sometimes I need to force refresh all devices to it. I have an admin panel button for this:

```
<button onClick="forceRefreshAllDevices()">Force refresh all devices connected to the website</button>
```

And the function code:

```
function forceRefreshAllDevices() {
    location.reload();
}
```

But it only does the admin's page. How would I send a reload to all devices connected? Something along the lines of an alert box that says "You will be reloaded in X seconds" or something like that would work great.

Answer (score -1):

You need to maintain a websocket connection to the server for all clients.

When admin page push the button, call the api to broadcast a message to all clients.

Once getting the message, refresh the page.